# Cannot getstatic file from assets in Angular SSR

Tags: angular, docker, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have deployed Angular Universal app in docker container. I want to get a static file located in assets/config/ directory via HttpClient. The problem is I am able to do it when I serve app locally, when I deploy it in Docker container locally as well, but when I deploy it to remote container I get logs like in the picture. Maybe I miss something in server.ts config?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8x3p.png

```
  private readonly configUrl = `assets/config/config.json`;
  ...
  this.http
    .get<Configuration>(`${this.configUrl}`)
```

Comment: With angular universal, all URLs should be absolute